# How to load CSS and JS file which is inside JAR File of application

Tags: java, css

I am not able to load my CSS and JS File which is inside jar file of the application. How can i access my CSS and JS file ?

Comment: Use Class.getResourceAsStream() or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream().http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: This question is rather meaningless unless you tell us which framework you are using; and what your current approach is - until then, Eriks generic answer is perhaps the best you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can place your CSS, JS, IMG/GIF etc. where your java and HTML resides and pack them into your jar file.
You can refert to them in CSS like this

```
    .myClass{
            background-image : url("resources/com.mycomp.mypackage.ReferenceClass/picture.gif");
    }
```

an e.g. render the references into HTML's head section like

```
    class MyComponent {
            add(new AbstractBehavior() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @Override
                    public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
                            response.renderCSSReference(/* look into JavaDoc*/);
                    }
            }
    }
```

or

```
    class MyComponent {
            add(new HeaderContributor(/* look into JavaDoc */));
    }
```

For more details visit [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Loading-resources-CSS-JS-from-JARs-td1868310.html)